# Can't use Docker CLI to manage bind mounts?

Tags: docker, devops

Docker documentation in the [Bind Mount page](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) says:

> You can’t use Docker CLI commands to directly manage bind mounts.

What does that mean? I certainly can create a bind mount using
`-v host_path:container_path`. What else is there to manage?

Answer (score 0):

For named volumes, the `docker volume` family of commands can manage them (create them, delete them, specify expert-level settings).  There's nothing equivalent for bind mounts, and as you note there doesn't really need to be.